# Add custom data to ADFS authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, ws-federation, adfs3.0

I have many applications and I'm switching the authentication to ADFS, and I need to add custom data, lets say an array of roles from a database after the successful login.

**Scenario Explained:**
Each application has its own roles in DB,
during a user authentication after an authorization request was sent,   `Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` will be invoked, so I can add roles as claims like this

```
 ((ClaimsIdentity)((ClaimsPrincipal)currentUser).Identity)
                    .AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "role1FromDataBase"));
                HttpContext.Current.User = currentUser;
```

But the `Application_AuthenticateRequest()` method will be invoked for each request and I don't want to request the roles from DB every time.
So, I need to add those roles somewhere to then be able to call them. Of course, Sessions and Cookies are not the best practice when I deal with API role based authorization.

Applications have Controllers and APIs and my ADFS on Windows server 2012

My OWIN Startup is

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,

                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications()
                {

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {   

                        context.ProtocolMessage.Wreply = "https://localhost:44329/";
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },

            });


        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after many hours i solved the problem
in `Startup` Class and   `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method 
we have to add claims with roles to `WsFederationAuthenticationOptions`
like this

```
 app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Wtrealm = realm,
            MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata,

            Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                // this method will be invoked after login succes 
                SecurityTokenValidated = notification =>
                {
                    ClaimsIdentity identity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    // here we can add claims and specify the type, in my case i want to add Role Claim
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "student"));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {

                    context.ProtocolMessage.Wreply = "https://localhost:44329/";
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },

        });
```